# Time limit Exceeded in if-else

Tags: c++, if-statement

Following is a function which change the value of array according to conditions:

1. If the difference between the array element and the next multiple of 5 is less than 3, round up to the next multiple of 5.
2. If the value of array element is less than 38, no rounding occurs.

Code:

```cpp
vector<int> gradingStudents(vector<int> grades) {
    int n = grades.size();
    int i = 0;
    
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(grades.at(i)<38) 
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if( (grades.at(i)+1) % 5==0 ) 
        {
           grades.at(i) += 1;
           i++;
        }
        else if( (grades.at(i)+2) % 5 == 0 && grades.at(i)>=38) 
        {
            grades.at(i) += 2 ;
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    return grades;

}
```

Hackerrank site saying " Time Limit Exceeded". I don't understand how can time limit exceeded when there is no loop (except the essential while loop). If I remove `i++` from each if statement and put it outside all if statements then its working fine, but the no. of statements remain same. please help me out

Comment: What happens if the grade is not less than 38 and the next two grades are not multiples of five?

Comment: Use a for loop instead. `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {....}`

Comment: @0RR if grade is 38 or more than round of to next multiple of 5, if next multiple - grade <3

Comment: Note that using `grades[i]` would be faster a little bit. Morever, you are calculating two modulo operations. In practice, you only need to calculate one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time Limit Exceeded` happens most often when the input size if very large, and/ or your logic takes a long time to process. One place I see in your code is, if there was a place where no `if` statements were satisfied, it will never be because `i` wont be incremented. Basically your loop will run forever.

You can either increment `i` in the end of the `while` loop (because anyway you will increment it),

```cpp
while(i<n)
{
    if(grades.at(i)<38) 
    {
    }
    else if( (grades.at(i)+1) % 5==0 ) 
       grades.at(i) += 1;
    else if( (grades.at(i)+2) % 5 == 0) 
        grades.at(i) += 2;

    i++;
}
```

Or use a `for` loop,

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(grades.at(i)<38) 
    {
    }
    else if( (grades.at(i)+1) % 5==0 ) 
       grades.at(i) += 1;
    else if( (grades.at(i)+2) % 5 == 0) 
        grades.at(i) += 2;
}
```

Comment: yes, I got it... I was thinking i will be incremented each time, but if grade>38 and other 2 if are false then it will become infinite loop. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only increments `i` when one of the conditions is met. It is not clear why you are doing this, because no matter what case the number `i` is, in the next iteration you want to check the next number not `i` again. Your conditions are not complete, in the sense that for example `i=42` does not match any condition. Hence, your loop will get stuck once it encounters the first such number.

Your current issue of an potentially infinte loop can be solved via

```
while(i<n)
{
    if(grades.at(i)<38) 
    {
    }
    else if( (grades.at(i)+1) % 5==0 ) 
    {
       grades.at(i) += 1;
    }
    else if( (grades.at(i)+2) % 5 == 0) 
    {
        grades.at(i) += 2 ;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Or the equivalent for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I tried similar code and it was working but couldnt understand the reason. Your explanation helped....